# How does emf depends on material of electrode?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, batteries

Concise Physics mentions that:

The emf (electromotive force)of a cell depends on 1) the material of the electrodes and 2)the electrolytes used in the cell.However it is independent of the a)the shape of electrode ,b)the distance between the electrodes and c) the amount of electrolyte in the cell

But the book doesn't explain anything' why the above things happens so. So I searched on the internet but I couldn't found any useful insights.

How does the emf(electromotive force) of a cell depends on the material of the electrodes? If the distance between the electrodes increases then more energy would have to be supplies by the battery for a unit charge to move towards the another electrode(terminal of the cell). But the book mentions otherwise. It tells that emf is independent of distance between the electrodes. So my second question is how emf can be independent of the distance between the electrodes? If the amount of electrolyte in a cell gets increased then certainly the volume of electrolyte would also increase and as a result the charges would have to travel a greater distance to reach the other electrode and therefore more energy per unit area would have to be supplied by the battery. But the books mentions the opposite (emf is independent of the amount of electrolyte) . So my third question is how emf is independent of the amount of electrolyte ?
At last the book mentions that emf depends on the electrolyte used in cell. So I thought of this Statement as: If the electrons find it harder to travel across an electrolyte in comparison to another electrolyte then certainly more energy would have to be supplied by the battery to the charges in order to cross the electrolyte in comparison to another electrolyte in the cell. Is my thinking on this matter correct or have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: You might try asking this same question on the [chemistry.se] site.

Answer (score 1):

In a cell the EMF of that cell, $E$, is determined only by the chemical reaction taking place in the cell. This is surprisingly simple to understand. Suppose the reaction produces a free energy change of $\Delta g$ joules per electron that the reaction produces. If this electron crosses a potential difference of $E$ volts then the work done is $eE$ joules, and to get the cell EMF we just set this equal to the energy released by the cell reaction:

$$ \Delta g = eE $$

We normally write this using the molar free energy released, $\Delta G$, and we have to replace the charge $e$ by a mole of electrons, which we write as $F$. Finally the reaction may produce more than one electron, and if it produces $z$ electrons we have to multiply our electron energy by $z$. The end result is:

$$ \Delta G = zFE $$

and this is the equation you'll see in your textbooks. Note that the cell EMF $E$ depends only on the cell reaction, not on the shape of the cell, the distance between the electrodes or the amount of electrolyte.

But the amount of electrolyte, the shape of the cell and the distance between the electrodes will affect the [internal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance), $r$, of the cell. This matters when a current is flowing through the cell because it will affect the voltage we measure at its terminals. When a current $I$ is flowing the voltage drops by $\Delta V = Ir$ so the voltage we would measure is:

$$ V = E - Ir $$

So *Concise Physics* is correct, but only because the term *EMF* has a specific meaning. It is the voltage we would measure when the current is zero i.e. when no electrons are moving. Since no electrons are moving things that affect the electron motion, like the cell shape, don't have any effect.

The *voltage* of the cell when it is producing a current does indeed depend on things like the shape.